# Reference request query parameter from response in spring cloud contract

Tags: groovy, spring-test, spring-cloud-contract

How to reference request query parameter from response in spring cloud contract tests.

Lets say I have a following code:

```
Contract.make {
    description("Contract description")
    request {
        method 'GET'
        urlPath('/some/url') {
            queryParameters {
                parameter 'user_id': $(consumer(~/\d+/), producer(111))
                parameter 'session_id': $(consumer(~/\d+/), producer(222))
                parameter 'segment_ids': $(consumer(~/"\[?(\d|,\s*)*\]?/), producer([1, 2, 3]))
            }
        }
    }
    response {
        status 200
        body([1, 2, 3])
        headers {
            contentType applicationJsonUtf8()
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to replace `[1, 2, 3]` in the response body with `segment_ids` value from the request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fromRequest().query("request_param")` [doc](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/2.2.0.M1/#_referencing_the_request_from_the_response)

In my case:

`$(consumer(fromRequest().query("segment_ids")), producer(~/"\[?(\d|,\s*)*\]?/))`

And a full answer

```
Contract.make {
    priority 1
    description("Should return available segments for pachinko-game service")
    request {
        method 'GET'
        urlPath('/segmentation-api/evaluation') {
            queryParameters {
                parameter 'user_id': $(consumer(~/\d+/), producer(111))
                parameter 'session_id': $(consumer(~/\d+/), producer(222))
                parameter 'segment_ids': $(consumer(~/"\[?(\d|,\s*)*\]?/), producer([1, 2, 3]))
            }
        }
    }
    response {
        status 200
        body($(consumer(fromRequest().query("segment_ids")), producer(~/"\[?(\d|,\s*)*\]?/)))
        headers {
            contentType applicationJsonUtf8()
        }
    }
}
```